# How to retrieve values from TempTable and set that values in local variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, rdbms

I have this code:

```
  DECLARE @TotalPayment DECIMAL(18,4)

  DECLARE @GetTotalPaymentAmount AS TABLE 
                                    (
                                        Amount DECIMAL(18,4),
                                        CurrencyId CHAR(3)
                                    )

  INSERT INTO @GetTotalPaymentAmount
      SELECT SUM(Amount), CurrencyId
      FROM [dbo].[fn_DepositWithdrawReport]()
      WHERE OperationTypeId = 2
      GROUP BY CurrencyId

  SET @TotalPayment = (SELECT Amount FROM @GetTotalPaymentAmount)
```

I am getting this error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value.

So yes, I  know that the issue in SET logic because `@GetTotalPayment` returning more than one row. If I am using for example `TOP 1`, it is working great, but I need all values of that table. How could I get all values and assign them to local variables from that table?

I am getting table like this

```
A  'C 
---'---
10 'USD 
20 'EURO
   '
```

and I need to retrieve all of these values.

Please note that I do not know how many rows will be returned from temp table and saying just declare second variable won't work. The whole point of this would be eventually pass that variables to function as input parameter.

Comment: Why reassign the table variable to another variable if you need all the values in the table? Also, this isn't a temp table. That is a different object with different properties and rules in SQL. Don't mix them up.

Comment: What do you need the values for?

Comment: `SELECT  Amount FROM @GetTotalPaymentAmount ` gets you multiple currency sums, if you want a specific currency add a where clause to filter it to 1 row, else you have to loop through them if you want to process each row one at a time.

Comment: Most likely you *do not* need to loop. If you explain what you're trying to do with the values I can almost guarantee you can do it with a set-based operation.

Comment: @So_oP . . . You *have* all the values in a table.  Just use `@GetTotalPaymentAmount `.

Comment: I want to pass each of that values  to the SCALAR valued function AS INPUT PARAMETER

Comment: You can use `CROSS APPLY`.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I modified your code slightly. Should work :)

```
DECLARE @TotalPayment DECIMAL(18,4)

DECLARE @GetTotalPaymentAmount AS TABLE 
(
  Id int identity(1,1),--added Id column
  Amount DECIMAL(18,4),
  CurrencyId CHAR(3)
)

INSERT INTO @GetTotalPaymentAmount
SELECT SUM(Amount),CurrencyId
FROM [dbo].[fn_DepositWithdrawReport]()
WHERE OperationTypeId = 2
GROUP BY CurrencyId

declare @i int, @cnt int
set @i = 1
select @cnt = COUNT(*) from @GetTotalPaymentAmount

while @i <= @cnt
begin
    select @TotalPayment = Amount from @GetTotalPaymentAmount where Id = @i
    --do stuff with retrieved value
    @i += 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

@So_Op

If you want the data to use in a `SCALAR` function then just do this

```
SELECT
     G.Amount
    ,dbo.FN_ScalarFunction(G.Amount)
FROM
   @GetTotalPaymentAmount G
```

If it's a `TABLE` Function then this works

```
SELECT
     G.Amount
    ,F.ReturnValue
FROM
   @GetTotalPaymentAmount G
CROSS APPLY
   dbo.FN_TableFunction(G.Amount) F
```